# How can I remove the inherited background?

Tags: html, css

I have this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/6ux3fzzc/

Code HTML:

```
  <div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="row2">
       TEST 
    </div>    
</div>

</div>
```

CODE CSS:

```
    .container{

   background:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.row2{
    background:transparent;
    color:white;

}
```

The .row 2 has background blue because it inherits from .container

How can I make it transparent to see the background color body?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

https://jsfiddle.net/6ux3fzzc/7/

I edited my post and I put a new instance ... now you know what I want?
I want .row2 be transparent and to see my background back.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question?

Comment: From your 'edit', i'm questioning why you would nest the div in the first place... [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/6ux3fzzc/8/)

Comment: So you want to see the background-image though the .contrainer, and though .row2, so only the test is there, "standing" on the background-image?

Comment: Are you trying to cut holes in elements with `background: transparent`?

Answer (score 3):

`row2` has a `background-colour` of `transparent`, so the blue will show through it.  If you need a background color on `row2`, then set it like this:

```
.row2{
    background:white;
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make it transparent to see the background color body?

It's already transparent but your background container is blue. That's why it's blue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the background color of row2 take background color of body. row2 is nested inside container and making row2 transparent will make it take background color of container.

So only way to achieve this is to explicitly specify the background-color of row2 as white

```
.row2{
   background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: I took this example from my site that I can not do what you said

Comment: @Gigel Can u elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The `background` of `.row2` is `Transparent`, and therefor you will see it as `Blue`, cause of the `background` in the `container`.

If you set your `.row2` `background` to `green` instead, you will see that its not inherited.

https://jsfiddle.net/6ux3fzzc/4/